# gdb showing incorrect back trace by pointing at the wrong line of code

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, gdb, abort

We can reproduce this problem with very simple example by having more than one abort call in our source code. In the below example code we have total of four abort calls with in different conditions but when we compile with optimization flag(-O3) we can see debug info for only one abort call . so where ever crash happens with in these four abort calls gdb always gives the one which has debug info.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void level_aa(int a)
{
        if (a == 0) 
          abort(); 
        if (a == 1) 
          abort();
        if (a == 2) 
          abort();

        abort();
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{       int D;
        D = atoi(argv[1]);
        printf(" Value = %d", D);
        level_aa(D);
        return 0;
}
```

Comiple the above code with optimization flags(-O3) and run with gdb to reproduce the issue.

```
>gcc -g -O3 abort_crash.c -o abort
>gdb ./abort
(gdb)run 1
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7ab2945 in *__GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00007ffff7ab3f21 in *__GI_abort () at abort.c:92
#2  0x0000000000400634 in level_aa (a=<optimized out>) at abort_crash.c:13
#3  main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at abort_crash.c:20
(gdb)
```

If we observe frame 2(#2), the crash actually happened at line no 9 but gdb showing line no 13. I can understand that it is happening because of optimization of source code. 
Is it possible to make gdb work fine in this case? (with out removing optimization)
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not necessarily, you should say waht is the EXACT VERSION OF *gdb* with this problem. And also the exact version of *gcc* and *binutils*. What platform and in case of Linux which distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to make gdb work fine in this case?

GDB *is* working fine in this case: it shows you what *actually* happened, which is ...

> (with out removing optimization)

... the compiler discovered that multiple paths lead to the `abort` function which can't return and have no side effects, and so *merged* these paths together, reducing the size of generated code. Just look at the resulting assembly:

```
(gdb) disas level_aa
Dump of assembler code for function level_aa:
   0x0000000000400620 <+0>: sub    $0x8,%rsp
   0x0000000000400624 <+4>: callq  0x4004b0 <abort@plt>
End of assembler dump.
```

All your `if`s are *completely* optimized out.

If you want to distinguish between the cases, you *must* make it known to the compiler that the paths are *not* equivalent.

Putting a `printf` call, or a call to external function that is not visible to the compiler in the current translation unit (the function itself may call `abort`):

```
extern int my_abort(int);  // must be in a different TU

void level_aa(int a)
{
        if (a == 0)
          my_abort(a + 1);
        if (a == 1)
          my_abort(a + 2);
        if (a == 2)
          my_abort(a + 3);

        abort();
}
```

Note: the `a+1`, `a+2` etc. are needed to prevent the compiler from merging separate paths. If you merely called `my_abort(a)`, the compiler may *still* merge them together as if you wrote:

```
if (a >= 0 && a <= 2) my_abort(a);
```

Note that even this external function approach may fail if you use whole program optimization.

Comment: I wonder if any compiler would optimise your use of my_abort to `if (a >= 0 && a <=2) my_abort (a + a + 1);`. Probably not...

Comment: Thanks for quick solution.

Comment: Thanks for quick solution. Unfortunately I can't modify our source code as it is a very big project. I just want to print a warning message in this case where we have more than one abort call. Because problem will come only in the case where we have more than one abort call. Does it really possible to know whether we have only one call or more than one  while using optimization ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any way to use volatile instead to make side effects for the purpose of optimization, without having additional code? Such as having a local variable assigned to itself.