# How to know whether any library function (abort) call used more than onetime or not in source?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, compiler-optimization, abort

In the below example code we have total of four abort calls with in different conditions but when we compile with optimization flag(-O3) we can see debug info for only one abort call . so where ever crash happens with in these four abort calls gdb always gives the one which has debug info.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void level_aa(int a)
{
        if (a == 0) 
          abort(); 
        if (a == 1) 
          abort();
        if (a == 2) 
          abort();

        abort();
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{       int D;
        D = atoi(argv[1]);
        printf(" Value = %d", D);
        level_aa(D);
        return 0;
}
```

Comiple the above code with optimization flags(-O3) and run with gdb

```
>gcc -g -O3 abort_crash.c -o abort
>gdb ./abort
(gdb)run 1
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7ab2945 in *__GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00007ffff7ab3f21 in *__GI_abort () at abort.c:92
#2  0x0000000000400634 in level_aa (a=<optimized out>) at abort_crash.c:13
#3  main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at abort_crash.c:20
(gdb)
```

If we observe frame 2(#2), the crash actually happened at line no 9 but gdb showing line no 13. I can understand that it is happening because of optimization of source code. Because if it is used more than once then the line number shows in gdb backtrace may not be correct. Is it possible to know whether abort call is used more than once or not by not seeing source ? If we know that the call is used more than once and also optimized then we can print a warning message. We are tool (internally using gdb) providers and we can't see source code of our users except their dump files.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help ..!!

Comment: If you cannot see the source what use is there for the line number?

Comment: We are just tool providers and proving backtrace of core dump and we should make sure that the backtarce is correct. But in this we cant get exact line number due to optimization of source code so we want to print a warning message to user.

Comment: Related: [gdb showing incorrect back trace by pointing at the wrong line of code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216397/gdb-showing-incorrect-back-trace-by-pointing-at-the-wrong-line-of-code)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not going to be possible.  Especially in the example you have given where *all* paths result in a call to `abort`, GCC will have most likely thrown away all check of `a` and just generated a single call to `abort`.

The line table information in DWARF (which maps addresses to source files and line numbers) does not, as far as I'm aware, have any facilities for making the line number a particular address maps to be conditional on some DWARF expression.  As a result, it is my understanding that a single address can only represent *one* source line, GCC will therefore have to pick a line number for each address.

In your example GCC has picked line number 13, which seems like a sensible choice as all of the previous code, that checks `a` is really redundant.

The only way you're going to get a more specific back trace will be to compile without optimisation, or to use some tool that is more powerful than GDB.

Comment: Especially abort is usually declared as no_return, so gcc knows, that the catch-all abort in line 13 is not called if a prior abort was executed, so the whole if ... can really be kicked out from the compiler.